# Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlConnection sqlconn;
            string connsqlstring = "server=localhost;user id=sql10217362;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=sql10217362 --debug";
            sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connsqlstring);
            sqlconn.Open();
            string queryString = "SELECT * from users where usuario='"+ txtUser.Text + "' and senha = '" + txtPass.Text + "';'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryString,sqlconn);
            MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Na hora de depurar ele da o seguinte erro:
Unhandled Exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.

Não sei se é pq estou utilizando o phpMyAdmin para administrar o banco de dados.

A DLL que utilizo é do site oficial do MySql

Comment: Qual a linha do erro?

Comment: Um cara resolveu um problema desse seu aqui: https://github.com/alvyxaz/barebones-masterserver/issues/68 Vê se te ajuda

Comment: Da erro aqui 'sqlconn.Open();'

Comment: Qual é a Inner Exception?